# Cannot Compare current_url to list in Python & Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium

I'm trying to skip the `current_url` if it is already in the list, but run into an error message.

My goal is to scrape a page, add that web page to a text file, then when I restart the scraping I want to compare the web page I want to scrape to the web pages in the list. When the web page is in the I want to skip it.

But this issue pops up that it cannot compare the `current_url` with the list:
This piece of code:

```
if cur_url in visited_urls:
```

Whole code:

## Open text file

```
visited_urls = 'C:/webdrivers/visited_p_urls_test.txt' # This specific the location of the text file on the PC
cur_url = driver.current_url

# Go to main test website
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
sleep(randint(1,3))

with open(visited_urls, 'a') as filehandle: # This opens a text file with the "Append to (add) mode."
    filehandle.write('\n' + cur_url)

# Go to main test website
driver.get('https://adwords.google.com/home/')
sleep(randint(1,3))

with open(visited_urls, 'a') as filehandle: # This opens a text file with the "Append to (add) mode."
    filehandle.write('\n' + cur_url)

driver.get('https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/')
sleep(randint(1,3))

with open(visited_urls, 'a') as filehandle: # This opens a text file with the "Append to (add) mode."
    filehandle.write('\n' + cur_url)

if cur_url in visited_urls:
    print 'I CANNOT comment because I already did before' 
else:
    print 'I can comment'

with open(visited_urls, 'r') as filehandle: # This opens a text file with the "Read" mode.
    filecontent = filehandle.readlines()    # readlines reads ALL lines in a text file
    for line in filecontent:
        print(line)
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to search a string in a file path(`C:/webdrivers/visited_p_urls_test.txt`), but you have to search in a file content:

```
if 'blabla' in open('example.txt').read():
    print("true")
```

in your case:

```
# open file, read it's content and only then search if cur_url exists already in a file
if cur_url in open(visited_urls).read():
    print 'I CANNOT comment because I already did before' 
else:
    print 'I can comment'
```

Comment: Many thanks Andrei, this worked :)

I do have to say that cur_url is not working anymore all of a sudden (it captured about:blank pages etc.), so now I just need to use the driver.current_url option.